# Is there any way to control the scrollSpeed for scrollTo()?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a function to autoScroll to a position on a sidebar where if it isn't on a option it will be scrolled to the nearest option. However, I want the scroll to slowly land on the option.

```
scrollableList.scrollTo({
            top: scrollTo,
            behavior: "smooth",
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not the standard `scrollTo` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo), [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-scroll) *[which is linked from [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollto)]*). There are various JavaScript libs that will do it for you, but you can't set the speed of the native behavior.

Comment: Although there is no inbuilt functions or methods for the scroll, can we use any other functions to built the logic for the scroll? I am having a hard time figuring it out

Comment: @Leon - Of course -- that's how the libraries I mentioned do it. For instance, you might use `scrollTo` with the default "instant" behavior repeatedly via `requestAnimationFrame`, moving through different positions over time to get to where you're going in the time you want to take to get there.